# How many columns confirm if statement

Tags: java

I need to change : `System.out.print((i+1) + " ");` so it doesn't show me which rows confirm if statement, but so it shows me how many rows confirm it.
right now it will say "3 6" but I need it to say "2"

```
int A[][] ={{0, 1, 2, 0, 2},
                {4, 4, 4, 4, 4},
                {0, -1, 8, 10, -1},
                {0, 3, -1, 2, 1},
                {4, 8, 4, 8, 12},
                {-1, -1, 2, 0, 1},
                {1, 8, 2, 4, -1},
                {8, 16, -1, 4, 0}};

System.out.println("results: ");
for (i=0; i<8; i++) {
    Count = 0;          
    for (j=0; j<5; j++) {
        if (A[i][j] == -1) Count++;             
    }
    if (Count >= 2 )
        System.out.print((i+1) + " ");
}
```

Comment: Move the `if` statement to outside the first `for` also your `Count`  variable must be outside it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understood it right. If so your solution would be:

Move the `if` statement to outside the first `for` also your `Count` variable must be outside it

```
int a[][] ={{0, 1, 2, 0, 2},
             {4, 4, 4, 4, 4},
             {0, -1, 8, 10, -1},
             {0, 3, -1, 2, 1},
             {4, 8, 4, 8, 12},
             {-1, -1, 2, 0, 1},
             {1, 8, 2, 4, -1},
             {8, 16, -1, 4, 0}};
int count = 0;          
for (i=0; i<8; i++) {
    int numbersOfMinus1 = 0;
    for (j=0; j<5; j++) {
        if (a[i][j] == -1){
            numbersOfMinus1++;
        }      
    }
    if (numbersOfMinus1>=2){
         count++;
    }
}

System.out.println("results: " + count);
```

Hint: since you are using Java you should read about the [Code Conventions for Java](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)

Comment: thank you this one works, and i will read about the Code Conventions for Java thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to move the condition `if (count >= 2 )` outside the for loop to print the `count` (which tells the number of arrays which hold '-1' element) as shown below:

```
int count = 0;         
for (i=0; i<8; i++) {   
    for (j=0; j<5; j++) {
        if (A[i][j] == -1) count++;             
    }
}
if (count >= 2 )
        System.out.print(count);
```

Also, ensure that you are following Java naming standards for variable names (starts with smaller case) like `count` (not as `Count`).